# HAProxy 1.5 SSL and many website

Tags: ssl, http, https, haproxy

Actually I'm hosting hundred website on Apache2 with some HTTP and some HTTPS, I'm preparing a new hosting infrastructure and I'm using HAProxy to loadbalance all my HTTP and HTTPS query on my apache/php-fpm cluster.

I'm using HA-Proxy version 1.5.8 2014/10/31 with SSL enabled.

**I want to use my apache configuration with all my certificates for this configuration with a simple HAProxy.**

**EDIT : HTTPS over TCP works fine**
<del>I would like to know if I can use HAProxy to redirect all my HTTPS traffic on my apache server without configuring all certificates on HAProxy, is it possible via TCP ?
I would like to get a simple HAProxy configuration and I don't want to edit haproxy.cfg each time after adding another website.</del>

What is the big difference if I use TCP instead HTTP mode if I use Apache behind my HAProxy ?

Can I use HTTP mode without setuping all my ssl certificates on haproxy.cfg ?

If you got any suggestion, I'm free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HAproxy, you have two methods of dealing with SSL: terminate it at the load balancer (HTTP mode and certificates are served by it) or passthrough with TCP. In TCP mode, HAproxy simply passes the connection to the chosen backend and it's up to the backend server (Apache) to serve certificates and such.

So to answer your question, no, you cannot use HTTP mode without having HAproxy control your certificates.

Comment: Thanks for these information Nathan, I'll use TCP for now then.